# is there 32bit firebird single file database 4GB size limit on 32bit linux?

Tags: linux, database, firebird

my 32bit firebird database is close to 4GB on 32bit linux centos
and I cannot find any clear answer is there a single database file
size limit of 4GB or not. Anotherwords, will application stop while 
database reaches 4GB size or not? I found info that 4GB limit is from 
old ages and not relevant anymore. In this page from firebird they say that size is limited only by the operating system,but they don't say which version of firebird is that, 32bit or 64bit.
http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq59/
thanks

Comment: The limitation is usually from the filesystem, not from the software. What filesystem are you using?

Comment: The file-system and the Firebird version matters. See details about the Firebird versions and their limitations here: http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-technical-specifications/

Comment: OS is a CentOS ver 6 I believe.  32bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed on [Firebird Technical Specifications](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-technical-specifications/):

> Maximum size of one database file : 
>   Multiple terabytes on most platforms; **limited by file systems** (4 GB or 2 GB on some platforms)

The bitness of the server is not related to this limit.

I'd suggest to check the documentation of your filesystem regarding maximum file size, but most modern filesystems don't have such low limits (that 2GB/4GB applies to FAT (and some other old filesystems) that are no longer broadly in use on servers).

Comment: thanks, that;s what I thought. My linux has file ext4 so should support at least 2TB.